# The anomalous Hall effect in Weyl semimetals

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-anomalies

Suppose the **semimetal** - the solid material, in which the conducting and valence zones are intersected at isolated points - the so-called **Weyl nodes**. Near this points, the Hamiltonian of electrons is effectively reduced to the Weyl-like Hamiltonian,
$$
H_{W} = \pm v_{F}\sigma \cdot (\mathbf p - \mathbf p_{\pm})
$$ 
where "$\pm$" is what we called the chirality in solid bodies, and $v_{F} <1$ is the velocity of their propagation.

Suppose $\mathbf p_{\pm} = \pm \mathbf b$, so that there is non-zero distance $2\mathbf b$ between the Weyl nodes for left and right fermions in momentum space. Such semimetal is the particular case of so-called Weyl semimetal.

How to explain qualitatively that non-zero $\mathbf b$ implies the existence of **anomalous Hall effect** (AHE), namely, the current
$$
\mathbf{J}_{\text{AHE}} \simeq \frac{e^{2}}{2\pi}[\mathbf b \times \mathbf E],
$$
in presence of electric field?