# "Mixed anomaly" in Weyl semimetal and its cancellation

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies, 1pi-effective-action, weyl-semimetal

***The introduction to the problem***

Suppose the **Weyl semimetal** (read please briefly the [definition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292830/the-anomalous-hall-effect-in-weyl-semimetals) before reading the question). Because of the effective nature of the chirality the parameters $b_{0}, \mathbf{b}$, which define the energy-momentum separation of the "left" and "right" Weyl nodes of chiral fermions $\psi_{L/R}$, are changed with coordinates. Therefore $b_{0},\mathbf b$ can be interpreted as the background axial gauge field 
$$
b_{\mu} = (b_{0},\mathbf b)
$$ 
(however, in fact this "gauge field" is observed itself).

In presence of the EM field, the existence of the axial gauge field leads to appearing of the **mixed chiral anomaly** in vector current $J_{\mu}$ conservation law. We have (neglecting the chirality changing scattering processes)
$$
\tag 1 \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu} = \frac{1}{24\pi^{2}}F^{\text{EM}}_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu, b},\quad \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{5} = \frac{1}{48\pi^{2}}(F_{\mu\nu}^{\text{EM}}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu, \text{EM}}+F_{\mu\nu}^{b}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu, b})
$$
Although this seems to be the "serious problem", in fact it's not hard to avoid it. Since $b_{\mu}$ is in fact physical, it is possible to **redefine the vector current** as
$$
\tag 2 J_{\mu} \to J_{\mu} - \frac{1}{12\pi^{2}}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}b^{\nu}F^{\alpha\beta,\text{EM}},
$$
so that the mixed anomaly in $(2)$ is cancelled.

***My question***

I want to write down the **local counterterm** in the quantum effective action $\Gamma[A,B]$, defined as
$$
e^{i\Gamma[A,B]} \equiv \int D\bar{\psi}D\psi\text{exp}\left[i\int d^{4}x\bar{\psi}i\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}\psi\right], \quad D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} - iA_{\mu} -i\gamma_{5}b_{\mu},
$$
which leads to the definition $(2)$. This counterterm seems to have the form
$$
S_{\text{B}} = -\frac{1}{12\pi^{2}}\int d^{4}x \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}A_{\mu}b_{\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}
$$ 
However, varying it with respect to the EM field $A$, we obtain
$$
\tag 3 J_{\mu} \to J_{\mu} - \frac{1}{12\pi^{2}}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}b^{\nu}F^{\alpha\beta,\text{EM}} + \frac{1}{6\pi^{2}}\epsilon_{\lambda\nu\alpha\mu}\partial^{\alpha}(A^{\lambda}b^{\nu})
$$
The last term, although it doesn't make the contribution into the anomaly, makes non-zero contribution into an electric current.

I understand that it can be interpreted as the ambiguity in the definition of the Noether currents in a sense that adding the 4-vector $\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{\mu\nu}$, with $\Phi^{\mu\nu}$ being antisymmetrical tensor, doesn't change the conservation law. However, this extra summand 1) is **not gauge invariant**, and 2) may be the source for EM field.

So, ***is it possible to eliminate this summand from $(3)$? If not, how to construct the correct counterterm which leads to $(2)$? If such counterterm doesn't exist, what is the reason for this?***

P.S. Note please again that $b_{\mu}$ is not in fact the gauge field.

P.P.S. The similar thing is discussed in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1230), in the end of the first column on the page 2 (there $B_{\mu}$ may be, for example, the $\rho$ meson field). However, an author doesn't write about the extra term in $(3)$.